# how to get latest tweets on my website?

Tags: twitter, twitter-feed

I have a blog in twitter like twitter.com/myname and I want to get latest tweets of my blog to display on my website. so that my website reader will be updated about my twitter blog.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A site. Unless you're specifically intending to write your own code to solve your problem, your question is off topic, and perhaps belongs on http://webapps.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fastest way is to use a [Twitter Widget](http://twitter.com/goodies/widgets). If you want a more customised one then you can generate one [here](http://www.widgetbox.com/widget/twidget).

OR

[How to Create Your Own Twitter Widget in PHP](http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/how-to-create-your-own-twitter-widget/)

[How to Create Your Own Twitter Widget in c#](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/asp-net/how-to-build-a-simple-twitter-widget-with-asp-net/)

Comment: but when I add twitter widget in myweb page it and run that page it is asking for username and password .why???

Comment: Which widget? Your own? Is yoour tweets protected? Please give more info

Comment: `www.twitter.com/widget`  here I got the widget. and my blog is `twitter.com/catchshizin`  and I think it is not protected.

Comment: Strange... Di you create one by going to http://twitter.com/goodies/widget_profile ?

Comment: fot creating `twitter.com/catchshizin` it asked only for email id thats it but this widget asking now username.